# Help on solving integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration

Hello Stack Exchange Users,

I was working on an integration problem, and I "simplified" the integral to the following:

$$\int \limits_0^{2\pi} (7.625+.275 \cos(4x))^{1.5} \cdot (A \cos(Nx) + B \sin(Nx)) \cdot (Z-v \cos(x)) dx$$

This integral may seem impossible (I have almost lost all hope on doing this analytically.)  If anyone can suggest a approach on attacking this monster, please suggest (It doesn't matter how ugly the solution will turn up to be.  I will churn it out.)

Note: Assume all values to be constants EXCEPT $x$

Edit: It may be that the function doesn't have a "simple" antiderivative.  If so, please post the more complicated antiderivative.

Edit 2: I like the approach converting the trig functions to exponentials, but I am struggling in expanding the first part of the integral ($(7.625+.275 \cos(4x))^{1.5}$) using the exponential notation.  Can someone help me on that?  Additionally, N IS an integer.

Comment: Can you show the original integral? Maybe it is more pleasant.

Comment: I think that **monster** is very a very appropriate qualifier !

Comment: I tried to play a bit with it. One approach that seems promising is as follows. Use Euler's formulae to express every trigonometric function in exponential form (like $\cos(Nx)=(e^{i Nx}+ e^{-i Nx})/2$) and let Mathematica expand the integrand. If I am not mistaken, the result is a long sum of terms, all of the same form
$$
\beta e^{i k x}\sqrt{c+d \left(e^{4 i x}+e^{-4 i x}\right)}\ ,
$$where $\beta, k, c,d$ are constants (they of course depend on which summand of this long sum you consider).

Comment: On top of that, if your $N$ is by any chance an integer, then $k$ seems to be an integer (not necessarily positive) as well. Therefore your problem can be restated in the simplified form: find the value of the integral $I(k,c,d)=\int_0^{2\pi}dx\ e^{i k x}\sqrt{c+d \left(e^{4 i x}+e^{-4 i x}\right)}$. With the substitution $e^{ix}=z$, this becomes an integral $\oint_{|z|=1}$ on the unit circle, for which there might be hope. Just my two cents.

Comment: @ Pierpaolo Vivo That is an interesting approach.  I will try it and see if I get anything.